# Huawei U8100 connection error to Blocks Editor in AppInventor

Tags: android, adb, app-inventor

I continue getting connection errors when I try to connect my Huawei U8100 to the Blocks Editor in AppInventor.

My phone shows usb debugging as well as usb connected when plugged into my pc.

I'm running Windows 7.

Any help on this question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two conversations from the App Inventor forums
  http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/forum/index.html#topic/appinventor/SePlzuZTG2I/discussion
  http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/forum/index.html#topic/appinventor/uldM6i6DwD4/discussion

There are some updates coming that make it easier to get connections working (or so I understand)

Gary